# How to handle 'ExtensionNotLoadedException' when using custom NER model in OpenNLP?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I'm trying to execute the OpenNLP model which I have trained for my customized names. I executed the below command to make customized model :

> opennlp TokenNameFinderTrainer -encoding UTF-8 -lang en -data c:\Users\nshah\Desktop\en-ner-person.train -model en-ner-personName.bin

I am able to successfully create model named **en-ner-personName.bin**.

Now i am trying to execute my program as below :

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import opennlp.tools.namefind.NameFinderME;
import opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel;
import opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException;
import opennlp.tools.util.Span;

public class NameFinder {

    public String nameFind(String inputText){

        String finalNames = "";
        try {

            TokenNameFinderModel tokenNameFinderModel = new TokenNameFinderModel(new FileInputStream("D://NISUM_OFFICIAL_WORKSPACE//opennlp//src//models//en-ner-personName.bin"));
            NameFinderME nameFinderME = new NameFinderME(tokenNameFinderModel);
            Tokenization tokenize = new Tokenization();
            String[] tokens = tokenize.tokenization(inputText);
            Span drugSp[] = nameFinderME.find(tokens);
            String [] sp = Span.spansToStrings(drugSp, tokens);
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            if(sp.length!=0){
                for(int i=0;i<=sp.length;i++){
                    string = string.append(sp[i]+"\n");
                }
                finalNames = string.toString();
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return finalNames;
    }

}
```

but after executing above program i am getting the below exception on console as mentioned :

```
Could not instantiate the opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory. The initialization throw an exception.
opennlp.tools.util.ext.ExtensionNotLoadedException: Unable to find implementation for opennlp.tools.util.BaseToolFactory, the class or service opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory could not be located!
    at opennlp.tools.util.ext.ExtensionLoader.instantiateExtension(ExtensionLoader.java:97)
    at opennlp.tools.util.BaseToolFactory.create(BaseToolFactory.java:106)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.initializeFactory(BaseModel.java:254)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:237)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:181)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel.<init>(TokenNameFinderModel.java:110)
    at com.naimesh.opennlp.DrugNameFinder.drugNameFind(DrugNameFinder.java:19)
    at com.naimesh.opennlp.TextFinder.main(TextFinder.java:18)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: Could not instantiate the opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory. The initialization throw an exception.
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.initializeFactory(BaseModel.java:256)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:237)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:181)
    at opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderModel.<init>(TokenNameFinderModel.java:110)
    at com.naimesh.opennlp.DrugNameFinder.drugNameFind(DrugNameFinder.java:19)
    at com.naimesh.opennlp.TextFinder.main(TextFinder.java:18)
Caused by: opennlp.tools.util.InvalidFormatException: Could not instantiate the opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory. The initialization throw an exception.
    at opennlp.tools.util.BaseToolFactory.create(BaseToolFactory.java:117)
    at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.initializeFactory(BaseModel.java:254)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: opennlp.tools.util.ext.ExtensionNotLoadedException: Unable to find implementation for opennlp.tools.util.BaseToolFactory, the class or service opennlp.tools.namefind.TokenNameFinderFactory could not be located!
    at opennlp.tools.util.ext.ExtensionLoader.instantiateExtension(ExtensionLoader.java:97)
    at opennlp.tools.util.BaseToolFactory.create(BaseToolFactory.java:106)
    ... 6 more
```

Please can someone help me on this issue, i tried lot many things and read blogs, but couldn't find something useful. That will be really appreciated if someone can give useful solution.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you've trained and created your model model.bin using a different version of opennlp say(1.6.0) and you're using say 1.5.3 in your code, this error occurs because of using models trained using a different version. check which version of opennlp you're using in the code(check .classpath)

Hope this helps! cheers!